# Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=5

Tags: ios, healthkit

`HKSampleType *stepType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierStepCount];`

when i want the steps ,it works;
and i want the `DistanceWalkingRunning` or  `ExerciseTime`, xcode show me the next message。

```
Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=5 “Authorization not determined 
UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Authorization not determined}”

HKSampleType *walkingType = [HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier: 
HKQuantityTypeIdentifierAppleExerciseTime];
```

somebody help me please.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
HKObjectType *stepType = [HKObjectType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceWalkingRunning];
NSSet *healthSet = [NSSet setWithObjects:stepType,nil];
```

It's too embarrassing! Just get the step's authorization, without the distance's.